# How to get resources from another application?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I found how to get resources from another application.

I researched many posts about this.

As that result, made ​​the following sources.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources themeR = null;
    try {
        themeR = getThemeResources("com.example.testskin01", this);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int resID = themeR.getIdentifier("activity_main2" , "layout", "com.example.testskin01");

    View themeLayout = (View)themeR.getLayout(resID);

    setContentView(themeLayout);    
}

private static Resources getThemeResources(String themePackage, Context context) throws NameNotFoundException {
    try {
        return context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(themePackage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I installed pakage of "com.example.testskin01" to test device.
with "activity_main2.xml".

When call the "resID", did not occur error.

But next line, called error from

```
"View themeLayout = (View)themeR.getLayout(resID);".
```

this is error message.

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser"
```

How can I solve this? Please suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

It's incorrect.
<strike>View themeLayout = (View)themeR.getLayout(resID);</strike>

It's correct.
View themeLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(themeR.getLayout(resID), null);